# Resize a multi-dimensional vector of form v[N]

Tags: c++, vector, stl

There's an answer available about how to resize a vector of type

```
vector<vector<int>> v;
```

But what if my vector is

```
vector<int> v[N];
```

and I want to resize it to make it v[M], how do I go about it? I can't find a way to do that since all the websites just talk about simple resizing.

Also are there any performance differences in declaration/operations of both methods?

Comment: It is not possible to resize things of the form `v[n]`. `n` must be a compile-time constant.

Comment: You can't.   In your second case, `N` must be a compile-time constant, and `v` cannot be resized during its lifetime.   Unlike C, which supports VLAs (variable-length arrays) such a feature is not part of standard C++.    It is possible to resize `std::vector`s because they, by design, manage their size dynamically.

Comment: even with VLAs you can't change the size after the array has been declared